# my test application of worklight for android stopped unexpectedly when i tried to run that on AVD?

Tags: android, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I have developed test application Using worklight for android environment. When i test that on worklight server it works fine, but when i tried to run the same on android virtual device (AVD) it throws an error message like 
**Sorry The application Test (process com.Test) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.** 
and the application terminates.
I am using **Eclipse 4.2** and android version for **AVD is 2.3.3**
 What is the solution of this...???
`

```
06-21 10:59:28.407: W/dalvikvm(1209): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/Test/Test; (14)
06-21 10:59:28.407: W/dalvikvm(1209): Link of class 'Lcom/Test/Test;' failed
06-21 10:59:28.427: D/AndroidRuntime(1209): Shutting down VM
06-21 10:59:28.427: W/dalvikvm(1209): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb607d4f0)
06-21 10:59:28.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1209): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 10:59:28.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1209): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.Test/com.Test.Test}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Test.Test in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.Test-1.apk]
06-21 10:59:28.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1209):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
06-21 10:59:28.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1209):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-21 10:59:28.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1209):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-21 10:59:28.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1209):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-21 10:59:28.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1209):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-21 10:59:28.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1209):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-21 10:59:28.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1209):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-21 10:59:28.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1209):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 10:59:28.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1209):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-21 10:59:28.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1209):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-21 10:59:28.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1209):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-21 10:59:28.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1209):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-21 10:59:28.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1209): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Test.Test in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.Test-1.apk]
06-21 10:59:28.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1209):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
06-21 10:59:28.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1209):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
06-21 10:59:28.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1209):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
06-21 10:59:28.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1209):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
06-21 10:59:28.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1209):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
06-21 10:59:28.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1209):     ... 11 more
`
```

Manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.Test"      
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0">    

    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="false"
        android:resizeable="false"
        android:anyDensity="false"
        />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <!-- Push permissions -->
    <permission android:name="com.Test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.Test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" >
        <activity android:name=".Test"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" 
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                  android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.Test.Test.NOTIFICATION" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Preference Activity  -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.worklight.common.WLPreferences"
            android:label="Worklight Settings">
        </activity>
        <!-- Push service  -->
        <!-- In order to use the c2dm library, an application must declare a class with the name C2DMReceiver, in its own package, extending com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBaseReceiver 
            It must also include this section in the manifest, replacing "com.google.android.apps.chrometophone" with its package name. -->
        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />

        <!-- Only google service can send data messages for the app. If permission is not set - any other app can generate it -->
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <!-- Receive the actual message -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.Test" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Receive the registration id -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.Test" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
</manifest>
```

Test.Java

```
package com.Test;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.worklight.androidgap.WLDroidGap;

public class Test extends WLDroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    /**
     * onWLInitCompleted is called when the Worklight runtime framework initialization is complete
     */
    @Override
    public void onWLInitCompleted(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.loadUrl(getWebMainFilePath());
        // Add custom initialization code after this line
    }
}
```

Comment: please share logcat traces..

Comment: No offense.. but we dont have any magic balls to see what is the problem without seeing your code.. Please check the logcat and inspect. If you cant find paste the code and the logcat data

Comment: put you java code and menifest code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVD 2.3.x has a known bug which prevents it from running WebView based apps. Use OS 4.x or 2.2.